# user path not merged with system path

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables

On my Windows 7 machine, for some reason the user path is not merged with the system path variable when I start a new command prompt. I have seen other related questions answered by a reference to a comment on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653.aspx):

> Found out that on Windows Server 2003, once the system PATH passes 1920 characters, the user PATH environment variable is no longer merged with it to set the process PATH environment variable, even though the full system PATH (even if larger) will be included in the process PATH variable.

However, my system path, when expanded, is only 1043 characters long, yet when I start up a new CMD, the user path is not merged into the system path. The user environment variables in general seem to be loaded, but path is completely ignored.

[image]

You can see from the picture that that `...AppData\Roaming\cabal...` portion of the user path does not show up from the `path` command when run in the CMD. The `%P64%` you see in the system path is expanded to `C:\Program Files`, but the character count after these are expanded is still only 1043.

Any thoughts on getting the user and system paths to merge properly for new processes?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I moved on to Windows 10 and haven't had problems with the path since.